# How to change the browser for accessing git help pages?

Tags: git, bash, default-browser

The problem is that whenever I'm trying to use git help pages, it is showing me the following error:

```
Suyash@BaazWorkstation MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Git (master)
$ git help log
/usr/bin/start: line 8: cmd: command not found
fatal: 'web--browse' appears to be a git command, but we were not
able to execute it. Maybe git-web--browse is broken?
```

I have tried the command

```
Suyash@BaazWorkstation MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Git (master)
$ git config --global web.browser chrome
```

before, but no effect, also tried using `google-chrome` in place of `chrome` but it didn't work either.

Please help with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally a `PATH` issue.

Try in a `CMD` to:

- use the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (uncompress Git 2.13 [`PortableGit-2.13.2-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.13.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.13.2-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, for instance in `C:\Git2.13.2`)
- set a simplify `PATH`.

Regarding the `PATH` issue, type (in a `CMD`):

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\Git2.13.2
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Then type '`bash`', and in the bash session, try your `git help log` commands again.